# Where did my last loop go?

Tags: perl

In the course of updating some legacy Perl code I came across a situation where a C-style `for` loop terminates prematurely.

### The Problem

The situation can be recreated as follows (same result for me on Linux and Windows):

```
$ perl
for($i = 0.8; $i <= 2.5; $i+=0.1){
    print $i, "\n";
}
__END__
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
```

The 2.5 is noticeably absent; it should've passed the `$i <= 2.5` conditional.

---

### The Fix

Realizing this may be due to floating-point representations, as outlined in [`perldoc perlfaq4`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-am-I-getting-long-decimals-(eg%2c-19.9499999999999)-instead-of-the-numbers-I-should-be-getting-(eg%2c-19.95)%3f), I updated the conditional:

```
$ perl
for($i = 0.8; sprintf( '%.1f', $i ) <= 2.5; $i += 0.1 ) {
    print $i, "\n";
}
__END__
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5      <--- Gotcha !
```

And service was resumed (or so I thought).

---

### The Verification

I wanted to prove that the final `$i` was indeed greater than 2.5, so I wrapped the increment in a [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) loop:

```
$ perl
for($i = 0.8;  $i <= 2.5; do { $i += 0.1; print $i, "\n"; } ) {}
__END__
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5      <--- Surprise!
```

The test results seem to indicate that floating-point representation is not the issue here.

What is going on here?

Comment: Silly question: What is the "__END__" all about?  Any chance your "missing 2.5" simply might not be *printing* (perhaps because you terminated the program before it had a chance to print the last bit of buffered I/O)?

Comment: @paulsm4 : `__END__` is a flag that indicates the end of an ad-hoc Perl script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're suprised that a value greater than 2.5 printed as `2.5`? Stop being surprised, that's normal floating point stuff. A plain print doesn't show all the digits. Try this:

```
printf "%.66g\n", $i
```

in place of your `print` statement. On my machine the final value printed is `2.5000000000000013`. Yours will probably be similar.

Comment: Yup, that's what I get as well! So the reason was right, but the test was misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because of float, it is not just as 2.5, you can use it as follows:

```
for ($i = 0.8; $i < 2.6; $i += 0.1) {
```

or you can see:

```
for ($i = 0.8; $i <= 2.5; $i += 0.1) {
    print $i, "\n";
}
print $i, "\n";
print $i <= 2.5 ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

output:

```
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5
FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of i is being increased at different times.  Notice your first value in the last run is 0.9, not 0.8.

The problem with the first one is floating point, try using 2.5001 in the condition.  Try it using integers, 8 to 25 by 1, the <= works fine.

```
for($i = 8; $i <= 25; $i += 1 ) {
    print $i/10, "\n";
}
```

Or

```
  print $_/10, "\n" for 8..25;
```

or

```
my $epsilon = .00000001;

for(my $i = 0.8; ($i - 2.5) <= $epsilon; $i += .1 ) {
    print $i, $/;
}
```

Comment: The first value in the last run is 0.9 because it's printing after the `$i += 0.1` increment. In the other examples it is printing before it.

Comment: So the same number of iterations is occurring.

Comment: Same number of iterations, but the final `$i` is 2.5, not 2.500001

Comment: Try using integers and divide by 10 for the answer, first one works fine.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid that workaround if possible. Can you recreate the same issue?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not after a fix. I want to understand the reason for the last loop not executing.

Comment: Yes, my initial results were the same as yours when I copied your code.  Going from 0.9 to 2.5 instead of 0.8 to 2.4 is not fix.  I changed the 2.5 to 2.5001 and it worked fine.  The correct solution is to not compare the numbers, but to compare the delta to some small epsilon.

Comment: The last loop did not occur in either of your cases, the same number of iterations occurred because of floating point ickiness, what printed was an accident of when $i was increased.

Answer (score 1):

Computer use a *binary* storage, not a *decimal*! If you store the decimal number 0.1 as a binary floating point number, it will result in an infinte number ob binary digits:

dezimal 0.1 = binary 0.000110011001100110011001100110011...

So if you don't use integers, you will get rounding-errors. The dezimal value 0.1 might be stored as the digital number 0.0001100110011001101 and this is dezimal 0.100006104

Adding 25 times 0.100006104 gives 2.50015259 and this is more than 2.5, so this last value is out of range.